# Compute mean and variance.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> Let $X$ be a random variable that is normally distribted with mean $\mu$
>   and variance $\sigma^2$. Compute
>
> 1. $E(X^2)$
> 2. $E(X^4)$
> 3. $Var(X^2)$

They also hint that for a standard normally distributed random variable $Z$ it follows that $E(Z^4)=3$.

I don't see how to use the hint given

Comment: How would you write $X$ in term of $Z$? $X = . \times Z +  . $

Comment: Z-score I suppose? $X=Z \sigma + \mu?$

Comment: Yea exactly now try to plug this equation in your expectation and work with the linearity of the expectation

Comment: I get to $$E(X^2)=E((Z\sigma+\mu)^2)=E(Z^2\sigma^2+2Z\sigma+\mu^2)=\sigma^2E(Z^2)+2\sigma\mu E(Z)+\mu^2.$$ Is it generally true that $E(Z^k)=k-1?$ In that case then the answer should be $$E(X^2)=\sigma^2+\mu^2?$$

Comment: @Parseval : It is not generally true that $\operatorname E(Z^k) = k-1,$ but your conclusion that $\operatorname E(X^2) = \mu^2+\sigma^2$ is correct. $\qquad$

Comment: But why isn't it generally correct then? What is $E(Z^2)$ I know that $E(Z)=0$.

Comment: @Parseval well done. You can go ahead and solve the other questions with the exact same method =)

Comment: @MaxFt Thanks mate!

Comment: @Parseval see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) "Moments" section for more moment and the formula with respect to $k$

Comment: @Parseval : You have $$ \begin{align} \operatorname E(Z) & = 0 \\ \operatorname E(Z^2) & = 1 \\ \operatorname E(Z^3) & = 0 & & (\text{the first counterexample to your guess}) \\ \operatorname E(Z^4) & = 3 \\ \operatorname E(Z^5) & = 0 \\ \operatorname E(Z^6) & = 15 \\ & \,\,\,\vdots \end{align} $$ And there's an obvious reason why all the odd-numbered moments are $0,$ namely the symmetry of the distribution.

Comment: So how could I have figured out these values?

Comment: In fact $\operatorname E(Z^k)$ is the number of ways of partitioning a set of $k$ elements into subsets of size $2.$ There is a reason found within the theory of cumulants, for associating those moments with that particular combinatorial question. $\qquad$

Comment: Do you know how to show that $\Gamma(1/2) = \sqrt \pi \text{ ?}$ That's probably the hardest part.

Comment: Reason I'm asking is because in order to solve this problem, one needs to know these values. Only $Z^4$ was given. @MichaelHardy No I have no idea. I think there is a proof of that in my book but I have not made it that far yet.

Comment: The standard normal distribution is $$ \varphi(z)\,dz = \frac 1 {\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-z^2/2}\, dz. $$ The basic facts about the gamma function that you need are $$ \begin{align} & \Gamma(\alpha) = \int_0^\infty z^{\alpha-1} e^{-z} \, dz \\ \\ & \Gamma(\alpha+1) = \alpha\Gamma(\alpha) & & \text{(shown by integration by parts)} \\ \\ & \Gamma\left( \frac 1 2 \right) =  \sqrt \pi & & \text{(more onerous to show)} \end{align} $$ If $k$ is even then write$\,\ldots\qquad$

Comment: $$\begin{align} \operatorname E(Z^k) & = \int_{-\infty}^\infty z^k \varphi(z)\, dz = 2\int_0^\infty z^k \varphi(z)\, dz \\ \\ & = \frac 2 {\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_0^\infty z^k e^{-z^2/2} \, dz \end{align} $$ Then write $$ \begin{align} u & = z^2/2 \\ \\ du & = z\,dz \\ \\ & z = (2u)^{1/2}  \end{align} $$ and observe that as $z$ goes from $0$ to $\infty$ then so does $u. \qquad$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\e}{\operatorname{E}}$\begin{align}
\e(X^4) & = \e((\mu+\sigma Z)^4) \\[10pt]
& = \e(\mu^4 + 4\mu^3\sigma Z + 6\mu^2\sigma^2 Z^2 + 4 \mu\sigma^3 Z^3 + \sigma^4 Z^4) \\[10pt]
& = \mu^4 + 4\mu^3\sigma \e(Z) + 6\mu^2\sigma^2 \e(Z^2) + 4\mu \sigma^3 \e(Z^3) + \sigma^4 \e(Z^4). 
\end{align}
Now apply what you were given about the expected values of powers of $Z.$

Comment: Thanks! Can you plese check if my answer to a comment above is correct?

Comment: +1 for your comments above !